# Android Share action provider

Tags: android

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.fullstory_m, menu);
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share)
mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)
MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultIntent());
```

whats wrong with the above code, coz it gives me null pointer exception 
the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<item android:id="@+id/action_share"
      android:title="share"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
      />
  </menu>
```

The imports

```
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
```

Stack trace

```
04-27 21:01:42.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 21:01:42.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 21:01:42.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at com.pitech.danny.nhl.FullStory.onCreateOptionsMenu(FullStory.java:32)
04-27 21:01:42.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2490)
04-27 21:01:42.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:407)
04-27 21:01:42.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:769)
04-27 21:01:42.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:201)
04-27 21:01:42.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
04-27 21:01:42.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
04-27 21:01:42.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
04-27 21:01:42.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
04-27 21:01:42.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-27 21:01:42.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-27 21:01:42.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-27 21:01:42.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Which is line 32 of `FullStory`?

Comment: Post your complete Activity code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue could be that `MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider` returns `null` in `onCreateOptionsMenu`.
Since your using android support library `ShareActionProvider` i.e., `android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider` , Your FullStory  `Activity` class should `extend` `ActionBarActivity`

```
public class FullStory extends ActionBarActivity {
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I solved it by checking my imports. Please make sure your imports are correct or not.

```
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
```

and in your xml  `android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"`